# Error returns for libcouchbase?

Tags: couchbase

I am having trouble with handling errors

I am curious about the exisitng error codes of libcouchbase.

I need to ensure that called APIs will not work under which environment

Append, Remove, Get, Set, Add, arithmetic, etc.

exact error codes will be very appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error codes may be found in `<libcouchbase/types.h>` (this file is automatically included by including `<libcouchbase/couchbase.h>` and must not be included directly.

The error codes are rather self-explanatory (some might be more exotic, though).

Additionally, you may call `libcouchbase_strerror(handle, errnum)` to get a textual representation of the error.